# When pinning a file within a folder to IPFS on pinata what determines the gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs link?

Tags: ipfs

I've added a folder with several files in it to IPFS via the pinata web interface.  I'd like to be able to address those files via the folder's CID.

For example:
gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/[folder CID]/file1
gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/[folder CID]/file2 etc

However, I can't seem to get a consistent URI out of the service.  Sometimes the link to the file will be gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/[CID] with "?filename" and then the file name appended and sometimes it will simply be gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/[CID]/ with the filename appended.  Any ideas?

What I'm currently getting:
gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/[folder CID]?filenamefile1

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use

https://ipfs.io/ipfs/<FOLDER_CID>/filename

Comment: Is there a way to get all files from a directory in one call?

Comment: You can view all files in a directory using a web gateway gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/<Folder_Cid>

Comment: @ObaJohn Is there a way to download it all into a zip. When using gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/<Folder_Cid> I just see each element and can click on it but I would like to download a zip of all elements.